# How to retrieve a truly large file using System.Net.Http.HttpClient?

Tags: dotnet-httpclient, .net-7.0

How to retrieve a truly large file using System.Net.Http.HttpClient?

Related: [Large HTTPResponseMessage causes .NET Core server process to run out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62193466/14768)

Calling `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync()` doesn't work because I need to look at the response headers.

The answer doesn't apply though. The file is too big to read into RAM at once. That shouldn't be a problem because I can use `ReadAsStreamAsync()` to get asynchronous stream, right? Nope! That call is really nice and tries to materialize the whole thing into a `MemoryStream`, which is impossible because it exceeds the maximum size of a MemoryStream.

How do I actually get the stream so I can read from it?

.NET version is .NET 7

Comment: Did you check if the server supports partial requests?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests#checking_if_a_server_supports_partial_requests

Comment: @ggeorge: It does not. The response is customized per call.

Comment: What do you want to do with the large file that does not fit into the memory? Do you want to stream to the file system?

Comment: @PeterCsala: Parse the file with a forward only parser and feed the result into the filesystem.

Comment: Have you considered to use [System.IO.Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/)?

Comment: @PeterCsala Find me the API surface to get a piplelines object form HttpClient and I'll consider it.

Comment: @Joshua Here is [simple example](https://github.com/tulis/system-io-pipelines-demo/blob/master/src/SystemIoPipelinesDemo/SystemIoPipelinesDemo/ReadHttpClientStreamPipeline.cs).

Comment: @PeterCsala: As described in the question, I cannot all HttpClient.GetStreamAsync() because I need to look at the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must request for the HttpClient to not buffer; thus must call SendAsync (or Send). The critical point is `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`:

```cs
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
using var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```